# jQuery DataTables - Sorting doesn't work when column is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

The tabs/search bar/page entries appear at the top of the table as expected. But they are not sorted when clicked. It's like it only looks at the first row.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {

    $('#aeotable').DataTable();

    } );

</script>

echo '

    <table id="aeotable" class="display">
            <thead>     
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Expiry insurance certificate</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>';



    // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['cop']}</td>
                <td>{$row['expo']}</td>
                <td>{$row['dec']}</td>
                <td>{$row['fil']}</td>
                <td><a download href=\"file/{$row['file']}\">Download</a></td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>";
    }

    // Close tabl
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Can u please provide a fiddle

Comment: @ashishraaj Iv not used fiddle before sorry. I wont be able to show my results from PHP will I?

Comment: I thought u were using HTML with javascript and  I am not an expert of PHP and haven't looked the tags, my mistake.

Comment: @rapidwaters actually it's not hard to copy html from browser "view source" or from browser dev tools html inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `<tbody>` for each row instead of one `<tbody>` for all rows.

Change to

```
echo '<tbody>';
// Print each file
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "        
        <tr>
            <td>{$row['cop']}</td>
            <td>{$row['expo']}</td>
            <td>{$row['dec']}</td>
            <td>{$row['fil']}</td>
            <td><a download href=\"file/{$row['file']}\">Download</a></td>
        </tr>";
} 

echo ' </tbody>';
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you